# The implementation of FunctionRange

Tags: functions, implementation-details

How exactly does the `FunctionRange` work?  What kind of algorithm does it use?  I looked it up in the [manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange.html) but it doesn't provide any references or even a name of the algorithm.

It also accepts a `Method` parameter but the only acceptable value according to the  manual is `Method -> {"Reduced" -> True}`.

EDIT: To clarify I mean the exact internal implementation.

Comment: Looks like this is a question only Wolfram employees can answer.

Comment: I was hoping they hang around here now and then.

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP asked from a algebraic resp. beginners point of view as of calculus, so is my answer:

It assume it is looking for `Discriminant`,

```
fr = FunctionRange[x/(1 + x^2), x, y]
```

> $-\frac{1}{2}\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2}$

```
fr[[1]]; fr[[5]];
fr == x/(1 + x^2)
```

> $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$

```
Plot[{x/(1 + x^2), fr[[1]], fr[[5]]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Solve[x/(1 + x^2) == fr[[1]], x]
```

> {{x->-1},{x->-1}}

```
Solve[x/(1 + x^2) == fr[[5]], x]
```

> {{x -> 1}, {x -> 1}}

```
Plot[{x/(1 + x^2), fr[[1]], fr[[5]]}, {x, -2, 2}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{-1, -1/2}, {1, 1/2}}]}]
```

[image]

```
x == y*(1 + x^2)
```

> $x=\left(x^2+1\right) y$

```
Expand[%]
```

> $x=x^2 y+y$

```
Solve[%, x]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 y^2}}{2 y}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{\sqrt{1-4 y^2}+1}{2 y}\right\}\right\}$

$\mathrm{Because, for\:a\:quadratic\:equation\:of\:the\:form\:}ax^2+bx+c=0\mathrm{\:the\:discriminant\:is\:}b^2-4ac$

Comment: OTOH, this is certainly not the complete story, I think. `FunctionRange[ArcTan[x], x, y]` and `FunctionRange[Sin[x], x, y]` are easily done, and `FunctionRange[LogisticSigmoid[x], x, y]` does not work without assistance: `FunctionRange[LogisticSigmoid[x] // FunctionExpand, x, y]`.

Comment: @J.M. I am only an amateur and would estimate supplements from you very much, please edit accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know about as much as you with respect to the internal details, so don't sell yourself short! My humble point was that what you propose might be the likely story for algebraic functions, but I am sure this is not what is done in the transcendental case.

Comment: @J.M. I think the OP asked from a algebraic resp. beginners point of view as of calculus, so was my answer. However, I estimate your opinion and your contributions exceptionally, it is sometimes even witty and always helpfully. Cheers and keep on good Coding!

Comment: I certainly mean the internals of Mathematica, not the algebraic method.  Say you write a proof and want to use this function to estimate something, how reliable is the estimate?  I imagine that with Mathematica being closed source these things are hard to determine but it's always worth a shot to ask.

Comment: @Louis I think your second comment to J.M. should be included in your answer. I mean the that begins with "I think the OP asked from a algebraic resp. beginners point of view [...]".